# New to Rust: Hangman game

Tags: beginner, rust, hangman

I decided to try my hand at a Hangman game to familiarize myself a bit with the language.

```rs
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};

fn main() {
    let stdin = stdin();
    let mut stdout = stdout();

    let to_guess = String::from("BENEDICT");

    let mut letters: u128 = 0;

    loop {
        // Replace unguessed letters of to_guess by underscores
        let current = to_guess.chars().map(|x| {
            if x <= 127 as char && letters & (1 << x as u8) > 0 {
                x
            } else {
                '_'
            }
        });
        // Add spaces between letters
        let current = current
            .map(|x| x.to_string() + &' '.to_string())
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join(" ");

        println!("Current word: {}", current.trim_end());

        if !current.contains('_') {
            println!("Congratulations!");
            break;
        }

        print!("Enter new letter: ");
        stdout.flush().unwrap();

        let mut letter = String::new();
        stdin.read_line(&mut letter).expect("Invalid letter");

        if letter.trim().len() != 1 {
            println!("Use only one ASCII letter");
            continue;
        }

        let letter = letter.to_uppercase().chars().next().unwrap();

        letters |= 1 << letter as u8
    }
}
```

The `to_guess` word is hardcoded, and there is an unlimited number of guesses.

To store letters already guessed, I use an `u128` and flag the corresponding bit. It should be ok since all ASCII letters are represented by `u8` < 128.

Can you help me review the code, are there "Rust" things I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Rust.  Here's some suggestions to get you started:

## Creating idiomatic use declarations

It is not common in Rust to bring a function into scope directly via a use declaration.  Instead, `io::stdin` and `io::stdout` are preferred.  See the section [Creating Idiomatic use Paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#creating-idiomatic-use-paths) in the book for more information.

## Using structs to self-document code

You included this sentence in your explanation of the code:

> To store letters already guessed, I use an `u128` and flag the
> corresponding bit. It should be ok since all ASCII letters are
> represented by `u8` < 128.

It is preferable to include this information in the code itself.  In this case, we can introduce a `struct`:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Default)]
struct AsciiSet {
    flag: u128,
}

impl AsciiSet {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { flag: 0 }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, letter: u8) {
        self.flag |= (1 << letter);
    }

    fn contains(&self, letter: u8) -> bool {
        (self.flag & (1 << letter)) != 0
    }
}
```

and modify the code accordingly:

```
let mut letters = AsciiSet::new();

loop {
    // ...
    if letters.contains(letter) { /* ... /* }

    // ...
    letters.push(letter);
}
```

## Checking for ASCII

`letter as u8` truncates the character if `!letter.is_ascii()`.  Check for this case and prompt the user accordingly.